# JavaScript Regex wierd behavior

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I noticed a very interesting behavior in JavaScript RegEx.exec function. 
if I run the same regex multiple times on a string that returns positive, it will return positive only half of the time.. (**I don't need to use .test**) I do need to capture some values from an input string.

I am using **Chrome 45.0.2454.93**.

[image: Chrome console output]

```
        var x = new RegExp("12|11","gi");
        console.log(x.exec("11,1,5,0")); // OK returns 11
        console.log(x.exec("11,1,5,0")); // NULL
        console.log(x.exec("11,1,5,0")); // OK returns 11
        console.log(x.exec("11,1,5,0")); // NULL
        console.log(x.exec("11,1,5,0")); // OK returns 11
        console.log(x.exec("11,1,5,0")); // NULL
```

I will up-vote a good explanation of this behavior.

Regards 
Erik.

Comment: [just read the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches)

Comment: True, I guess it is something that can bugle your mind if you are coming from a C# programming language..